# PageViewController custom transition styles

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

Is it possible to use custom transition style for PageViewController rather than using Page Curl or Scroll transitions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stick any of these given transitions, or you could imitate pageviewcontroller by yourself and add your own transition.